Can “〜などない” or “〜なんてない” also mean “not remotely”?
I keep seeing “〜などない” in many contexts where I feel this is the only interpretation that makes sense even though I can't find anything on the internet about it, such as say “その人に車を運転する資格などない。” “父として振る舞う資格などない。” where the context seems to imply that something isn't even close to or vaguely resembles the part marked with 〜などない” as in:

He's nowhere near qualified to drive a car.
I'm not remotely qualified to act as your father.

Is this understanding correct or is there something more to it?

など/なんて/なんか is a belittling/derogatory particle, and its core meaning is always "such a thing as" or "something like". In your cases, など is used to indicate that the "qualification" is not even something worth discussing, i.e., it's out of the question. While "nowhere near" or "(not) remotely" might be an acceptable translation in those specific cases, you shouldn't assume that they're the basic meaning of など.

私は父親に全く似ていない。
I don't remotely resemble my father.
私は父親になど似ていない。
No way I resemble a person like my father.
I'm not like my father, of all people.

The former is a neutral sentence, but the latter sounds like the speaker hates their father.
